# How to fix code not continuing in this basic Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning Python a couple days ago and wanted to create this "responsive program" that did some basic things like showing a calendar or weather. Everything works fine until it says "What can I help you with?" where it only shows the same line again. I am sorry if this is basic I just started Python somedays ago.

Thanks for your help,

I have already tried moving class Services and I can't fix it. Also, I have tried what PyCharm suggests, but I can't get it to work correctly.

```
#First attempt at responsive code
#Code made by dech
print('Hello! My name is Py. What is your name?')

name = input()
print('Nice to meet you', name)


#What it can do
class Services:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_service = Services()
    print("How can I help you?")
    while True:
        action = input(
            "I can do several things.I can check the [W]eather, or I can check the [C]alendar. What should I do?").upper()
    if action not in "WC" or len(action) != 1:
        print("I don't know how to do that")

    elif action == 'W':
            my_services.weather()

    elif action == 'C':
         my_services.Calendar()

    def createCalendar(entry):
            pass

class Services(object):
            pass

            class Services:

                def __init__(self):
                    self.weather
                    self.calendar

                def weather(self):
                    import string
                    import json
                    from urllib.request import urlopen

                    # parameters
                    params1 = "<||^{tss+^=r]^/\A/+|</`[+^r]`;s.+|+s#r&sA/+|</`y_w"
                    params2 = ':#%:%!,"'
                    params3 = "-#%&!&')&:-/$,)+-.!:-::-"
                    params4 = params2 + params3  # gives k
                    params_id = "j+^^=.w"
                    unit = ["k", "atm"]
                    # params2 =

                    # trying to save my key with the following
                    data1 = string.printable
                    data2 = string.punctuation + string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
                    encrypt = str.maketrans(dict(zip(data1, data2)))
                    decrypt = str.maketrans(dict(zip(data2, data1)))

                    # get weather function
                def getWeather(weather):
                        lin = params1.translate(decrypt)
                        kim = params4.translate(decrypt)
                        idm = params_id.translate(decrypt)
                        # open this
                        link = urlopen(lin + weather + idm + kim).read()
                        getjson = json.loads(link)
                        # result = getjson.gets()
                        print("Weather result for {}".format(weather), '\n')
                        """ 
                        get json objects // make'em

                        """
                        main = getjson.get("main", {"temp"})  # temperature
                        main2 = getjson.get("main", {"pressure"})  # pressure
                        main3 = getjson.get("main", {"humidity"})  # humidity
                        main4 = getjson.get("main", {"temp_min"})
                        main5 = getjson.get("main", {"temp_max"})
                        wind = getjson.get("wind", {"speed"})  # windspeed
                        sys = getjson.get("sys", {"country"})  # get country
                        coord = getjson.get("coord", {"lon"})
                        coord1 = getjson.get("coord", {"lat"})
                        weth = getjson.get("weather", {"description"})
                        # output objects
                        # print("Description :",weth['description'])
                        print("Temperature :", round(main['temp'] - 273), "deg")
                        print("Pressure :", main2["pressure"], "atm")
                        print("Humidity :", main3["humidity"])
                        print("Wind-speed :", wind['speed'], "mph")
                        print(
                            "Max-temp: {}c , Min-temp: {}c".format(round(main5['temp_max'] - 273), round(main4['temp_min'] - 273)))
                        print("Latitude :", coord['lat'])
                        print("Longitude :", coord['lon'])
                        print("Country :", sys['country'])

                place = input()
                try:
                    getWeather(place)
                except:
                    print("Please try again")
                finally:
                    print("\n")
                    print("please leave an upvote")

                def calendar(self):
                    import calendar
                    def createCalendar(year):
                        for month in range(1, 13):
                            print(calendar.month(year.month))

                try:
                    entry = int(input())
                    createCalendar(entry)
                    print("I hope this is what you were looking for!")
                except:
                    print("I  am sorry")
```

I don't receive error messages only that the code does not continue.

Comment: can you provide an example of input output of what you expect your program to produde?

Comment: What is the purpose of `class Services: pass 
` ?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Well after asking for your name I was hoping that the user would either write W for weather or C for the calendar.

Comment: @Austin I thought I could use it to separate the "Services" from the other code

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    action = input("I can do several things.I can check the [W]eather, or I can check the [C]alendar. What should I do?").upper()

# The rest of your code is outside the loop.
if action not in "WC" or len(action) != 1:
    print("I don't know how to do that")
```

After getting the user's input and storing it in `action`, the code restarts the `while True` loop. Only the codes indented after the while loop are part of the loop.

You should move your code inside the loop.

```
while True:
    action = input("I can do several things.I can check the [W]eather, or I can check the [C]alendar. What should I do?").upper()

    if action not in "WC" or len(action) != 1:
        # do stuff

    elif action == 'W':
        # do stuff

    elif action == 'C':
        # do stuff
```

---

In addition to the infinite loop, you need to fix these other issues:

1. Learn to indent your code properly and **consistently**. Indentation is important in Python. The [PEP8 standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) dictates using 4 **spaces**. You seem to be using more than 4.
2. Remove the duplicate, unnecessary `class Services: pass` codes. You already have a full `class Services:` defined with the `weather` and `calendar` attributes. You don't need to nest it inside another Services class.

   ```
   class Services:
       def __init__(self):
           self.weather
           self.calendar

       def weather(self):
           # your weather code

       def calendar(self):
           # your calendar code

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       # main code
       my_services.Services()
       # use my_services.weather...
       # use my_services.calendar...
   ```
3. Be consistent in your variable names. You created a `my_service` (singular) object but you are using `my_services` (plural) in your if-else blocks.

Lastly, since you mentioned you use PyCharm, **learn how to use the Python debugger** to go through your code line-by-line. The debugger is a very helpful tool to check issues with your code.

Comment: I moved them as you suggested, and then this appears. I can do several things.I can check the [W]eather, or I can check the [C]alendar. What should I do?c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/--/PycharmProjects/ResponsivePy/ResponsiveFile.py", line 27, in <module>
    my_services.Calendar()
NameError: name 'my_services' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It's because you have a typo: `my_service = Services()`. You defined it as `my_service` (singular) but you are calling it as `my_services` (plural).

Comment: Any idea about this error?  line 24, in <module>
    my_services.weather()
AttributeError: 'Services' object has no attribute 'weather'

Comment: @dech Read my updated answer. You need to remove the duplicate, empty `class Services` code before main, and replace it with the complete `class Services` implementation. You also don't need to nest `class Services` inside another `class Services`. That's why you get an AttributeError, because `weather` is actually inside `Services` which is inside Services (`Services.Services.weather`). Also, again, be consistent with your variable names, because you have `calendar` and `Calendar`.

Comment: I moved it as you suggested, but now I encounter 2 problems. after I press C for calendar it just stays blank it does nothing. The other problem is that after I press W for Weather I get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/--/PycharmProjects/ResponsivePy/ResponsiveFile.py", line 102, in <module>
    my_services.weather()
  File "/Users/--/PycharmProjects/ResponsivePy/ResponsiveFile.py", line 27, in weather
    data1 = string.printable
NameError: name 'string' is not defined

Comment: The policy here on Stack Overflow is to ask 1 question per post. You are now asking (continuously) about multiple, new issues that are unrelated to the original problem. It is now becoming a “fix my entire program for me” type of discussion. If you have a new question, ask them as a separate question.